# While and Append in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to Call Api in a while loop and append the dataframe. But it is not appending .

```
#Max timestamp
MaxTs = 1635876000

api_key = "api_key"


cnt = 0
while cnt < 4:

url = f"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histohour?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=2000&toTs={MaxTs}&api_key={api_key}"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
price_df = pd.DataFrame(data['Data']['Data'])



i = 0
reccnt = 2000
while i < reccnt:
    currTs = price_df.iloc[i]['time']
  
    
    if currTs < MaxTs:
        MaxTs = currTs
    i = i + 1
    
if cnt == 0:
    #Copying the Orginal df to new df.
    newdf = price_df.copy()
  
else:
    #when counter increases append the df.
    newdf.append(price_df)
    
  
print(MaxTs)
cnt = cnt + 1
```

Comment: Should your if/else be indented to be inside the while loop ?

Comment: You mean within 2nd loop?

Comment: I'm just wonder if you intended to have the if/else within the while loop

Comment: Variable `cnt` doesn't seem to be incremented and condition `if cnt == 0` remains `True`

Answer (score 0):

You should increase `cnt` inside the `while` loop, not outside.
But after you perform a correction you will get several copies of the same `price_df`. Is that what you are trying to get?

Comment: No, but may be  i will delete the duplicates. let me work on that